# Duplicate acc on accepting personal answer in activity view

Tags: support, accepted-answer, recent-activity

Is this a bug? A fluke? I don't really know how to go about duplicating it except for the obvious (create another answer, mark it accepted). Not sure if my being mod over there has anything to do with it (if so, another mod can quickly jump on this as "not an issue").

[image: shows duplicate acc on list]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You asked the question and accepted your own self-answer, for two acceptance events. This is also why there's no actual reputation bonus for either one. But if you check the links, one should point to the question while the other would point to the answer.

Comment: oh /facepalm I didn't even hover it :( I'm so dumb sometimes. Ah well, at least there's a record for the next person to look not so dumb. Also, I didn't find it in a cursory search :\ ~ "You can accept an answer in 10 minutes"

Comment: @drachenstern Cursory searches are more likely to turn up one of the "Multi-acceptance" bugs in which answers *were* accepted multiple times.

Comment: GAH searchfu confounds me again! :p